# Arduino Variable Size and Fixed Point

Tags: arduino, fixed-point

I am working on a project where I need to use Fixed Point math, I am not able to figure out why the numbers are "Rolling Over", I was able to get a large enough number when I changed the shift amount from 16 to 8 and finally to 4. Here is the code I am using at present:

```
#define SHIFT_AMOUNT 8
#define SHIFT_MASK ((1 << SHIFT_AMOUNT) - 1)
#define FIXED_ONE (1 << SHIFT_AMOUNT)
#define INT2FIXED(x) ((x) << SHIFT_AMOUNT)
#define FLOAT2FIXED(x) ((int)((x) * (1 << SHIFT_AMOUNT)))
#define FIXED2INT(x) ((x) >> SHIFT_AMOUNT)
#define FIXED2FLOAT(x) (((float)(x)) / (1 << SHIFT_AMOUNT))

int32_t test = FLOAT2FIXED(1.00);

void setup()
{
   Serial.begin(57600);
}

void loop(){

   test += FLOAT2FIXED(1.00);
   Serial.println(FIXED2FLOAT(test));

}
```

And the output:

```
1
2
3

...

127
-128
-127
-126
```

When SHIFT_AMOUNT = 8 I am only able to store variables from -128 to 128 but since I am using a 32 bit variable shouldn't a 16 bit shift move the decimal point to the "Middle" leaving 2 16 bit sections, one for the Whole Number and the other for the decimals? Shouldn't the whole range of the int32_t be −2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 with the shift at 16? Is there a setting that I am missing or am I just way off with how this works?

If SHIFT_AMOUNT = 4 I get a range that I need but this doesn't seem right since all the other examples that I have seen online use the 16 bit shift.

[Here is a link showing what I am looking to do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067510/fixed-point-arithmetic-in-c-programming)

### **EDIT**

If I have this correctly, when shifting 8 bits when using a 16 bit wide type that leaves 8bits for the whole and 8 for the fractal leaving a range of -128 to 128. Hence the need for using the 4bit shift increasing the range of the whole to -32,768 to 32,767 is this correct? If that is right then is the int32_t not a true 32 bit wide?

### **EDIT2**

Patrick Trentin pointed out where I was going wrong. Everything was correct except for the part I copied from the linked question. I was casting to a **int** not a **int32_t**. The int type is 16bits wide, hence having to use 4 to get the range I needed.

Comment: Why not use one of the fixed point primitives that avr-gcc [already supports](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/avr-gcc#Fixed-Point_Support)?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams One of the reasons that I am going through this is to one learn how this works, what the results should be, how it was made and to get a better understanding.  If I don't understand how this works and why it works then I will not know if a library is giving me an erroneous value or if my other code has a bug. I think I understand how this works, I updated my question to try and make it a little more clear.

Comment: @AndyBraham the size of `(int)` in Arduino is `16-bit`, why did you cast the value to `int` in the macro rather than `int32_t` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
#define FLOAT2FIXED(x) ((int)((x) * (1 << SHIFT_AMOUNT)))
```

into this:

```
#define FLOAT2FIXED(x) ((int32_t)((x) * (1 << SHIFT_AMOUNT)))
```

---

**Rationale**: the size of `int` is `16-bit` on an Arduino Uno (see the [documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Int)), this caps the size of the values that you are storing within your `int32_t` variable to *16 bits*.

---

**EDIT**:

The fact that `int16_t` is an alias of `signed int`, which is an alias for `int`, can be corroborated by either looking at the [online documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Int) or at the content of the file

> *arduino-version*/hardware/tools/avr/lib/avr/include/stdint.h

among the *Arduino Uno* sources:

```
/** \ingroup avr_stdint
    16-bit signed type. */

typedef signed int int16_t;
```

Comment: I missed that one, I knew there was some sort of small issue thank you. Is that a typical setting to have the variable without any postfix smaller than the rest? I mean I would of thought that int = highest possible (int32_t).

Comment: @AndyBraham I extended my answer to answer your question, hope it helps. (: