# How to properly round up doubles in C?

Tags: c, variables, rounding

For some reason, `ceil(x)` rounds up round numbers to x+1.

For example:

```
double og_grade = 50;
double fact_grade = ceil(og_grade*1.1);
```

`og_grade*1.1` should be 55.0000, but `ceil(og_grade*1.1)` returns 56.0000

Note that `og_grade` is always a whole number.

Comment: You say that og_grade*1.1 == 55.0000.... - what comes after the "...."? Is it 55.0000....01 by any chance?

Comment: @WillihamTotland: No, that's a bad way. There's an infamous rounding bug in Java that was not fixed until version 5 that was put down to that approach. `ceil`, `floor`, and `round` are in the C standard library for good reason.

Comment: `55*1.1` results in `55.00000000000000710542735760100185871124267578125`, so `ceil` is correct in returning `56`. https://ideone.com/74a7IE

Comment: @mch, assuming IEEE754 `double`.

Comment: @Hanik: To fix this issue, consider modifying your code to work with integers or [fixed point arithmetic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10067510/69809). Floating point math is nice for scientific calculations, but breaks badly otherwise; you should never attempt to represent currency using floating point math, for example.

Comment: Use `printf("%.21e\n", og_grade*1.1);` to see why.

Comment: @WillihamTotland The "add 0.5 and truncate to int" trick can fail when 1) sum is outside `int` range, 2) the sum is not exact - in effect, failure due to [double rounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Double_rounding).

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica So noted.

Comment: @hanik, try  `(int)og_grade * 11 + 5)/10`.

Answer (score 3):

> I tried the ceil(x) function, but for some reason when x in already
>   round, it rounds it up to x+1

No that would mean that the implementation of `ceil` was defective. Not impossible but *extremely* unlikely.

It's likely that the `x` for which this effect is observed is in fact not integral, and the decimal portion is omitted from the formatting or debugger.

Assuming IEEE754, the *closest* `double` to 1.1 is slightly larger than that; this most likely accounts for your result.

In your case, given that `op_grade` is in fact a whole number, your best bet is to use an `int` for `op_grade`, and multiply by 11 instead; the subsequent rounding checks are then both trivial and exact.

Comment: In short, my task is to receive a grade and return it with 10% extra, always rounded up. If it's 60.5, it returns 61. If it's 55, it returns 55. If it turns out larger than 100, it should return 100.
I tried returning ceil() of the original grade multiplied by 1.1.
All very very basic stuff but I've been going crazy over this issue.
What would be the best execution for this?

Comment: @Hanik: Is `og_grade` always a whole number?

Comment: Yes, and so is `fact_grade` supposed to be once it has been rounded up.