# How to multiply by Decimal Quantities without using Floating Point? [C17]

Tags: c, floating-point, integer, currency

I'm trying to code a sort of ATM machine in C. I've been **Strongly** advised to not use floating points at any time when dealing with currency.
In my code the user can select which currency they want to work with ($,E (€),P (pound)).
The problem arrises when trying to make an exchange from one currency to another one, as they cannot be represented by an `int` variable.

**The Exchange Rates Chosen:**
US to EU is  0.91
US to UK is  0.79
*Note that these aren't constants, the user can change them.*

**Code fragment:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Currency {
    int main;
    int frac;
    char symb[1];
} Dinero, Banka;

struct Currency Dinero = {
    0, 0, "E" //E is €
};

struct Currency Banka = {
    0, 0, "$"
};

int UStoEU_ExchangeRate = 91 / 100, UStoUK_ExchangeRate = 79 / 100; //Exchange rates
int EU_US_ExchangeRate = 110 / 100, UK_US_ExchangeRate = 127 / 100;

int CalcCuentmain() { //Function that takes the value from "Banka"(always in $) and translates them into the different currencies the user asked.

    int RVmain; //Is used in int main() to print the RealValue times the exchangerate.
    if (strcmp(Dinero.symb, "$") == 0) {
        RVmain = Banka.main;
        return RVmain;
    }
    if (strcmp(Dinero. symb, "E") == 0) {
        RVmain = US_EU_ExchangeRate * Banka.main; //Doesn't Work
        return RVmain;
    }
    if (strcmp(Dinero.symb, "P") == 0) {
        RVmain = US_UK_ExchangeRate * Banka.main; //Doesn't Work
        return RVmain;
    }
}

int main() { ... }
```

From the code, line:

```
    RVmain = US_EU_ExchangeRate * Banka.main; //Doesn't Work
```

This won't change the value of `RVmain` as the `US_EU_ExchangeRate` is rounded to 1.

Is there any way to multiply `RVmain` by a decimal quantity (in this case `0.91`) without using floating points?
If not how do we deal with problems like this when working with currencies?

**Important Notes:**

- I'm **very** new to programming so apologies in advance if this is quite a simple problem or badly phrased.
- I represent currency using a structure. Using `Dinero` when there is a user input, and `Banka` to store "the real value". `int main` is the number before the decimal dot, `int frac` is the number after the decimal dot.

  ```
      struct Currency {
          int main;
          int frac;
          char symb[1];
      } Dinero, Banka;
  ```
- I know that even this fragment alone might(is) poorly written, but please remember I'm a beginner :(
- If there is some ambiguity in my question I'll happy clarify it.

Comment: I think you are looking for [fixed point arithmetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067510/fixed-point-arithmetic-in-c-programming).

Comment: If you have 0.91, multiply by 91 then divide by 100. No floating point used.

Comment: The alternative to floating-point is *fixed*-point.  That does not necessarily mean limiting yourself to whole-unit precision.

Comment: You can use `long long int` for money if `int` isn't big enough.

Comment: Re “they cannot be represented by an int variable”: Yes, they can. Use appropriate units. €.91 is 91 euro cents, and £.79 is 79 pence. A bigger issue than that is rounding properly when converting currencies. Unless you want only truncation, you will need to deal with fractions or otherwise compute the desired quotient given there may be a non-zero remainder.

Comment: @WeatherVane no if you need a specific size use types from stdint.h, like int64_t

Comment: @Fredrik `long long int` is *at least* 64 bits.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to multiply RVmain by a decimal quantity (in this case 0.91) without using floating points?

Scale by 91, then divide by 100.

1. Use a wide enough integer math to avoid overflow.
2. Consider how you want to *round* the result.  *Round to nearest, half-way away* for example.  Simply add half the denominator before the division. Also consider negative dollar amounts.
3. Assumption: conversion rate is never negative.

Example:

```
int US_EU_ExchangeRate_numerator = 91;
int US_EU_ExchangeRate_denominator = 100;
long long t = (long long)US_EU_ExchangeRate_numerator * Banka.main;
if (Banka.main >= 0) { 
  RVmain = (int) ((t + US_EU_ExchangeRate_denominator/2)/US_EU_ExchangeRate_denominator);
} else {
  RVmain = (int) ((t - US_EU_ExchangeRate_denominator/2)/US_EU_ExchangeRate_denominator);
}
```

---

To be more like floating point common math, more advanced code would use *Round to nearest, half-way to even*.   *Something* like:

```
long long t = (long long)US_EU_ExchangeRate_numerator * Banka.main;
int RVmain = (int) (t / US_EU_ExchangeRate_denominator);
int remainder = t % US_EU_ExchangeRate_denominator;
if (Banka.main >= 0) { 
  RVmain += +2*remainder > US_EU_ExchangeRate_denominator || 
      (RVmain % 2 && 2*remainder == US_EU_ExchangeRate_denominator);
} else {
  RVmain -= -2*remainder > US_EU_ExchangeRate_denominator || 
      (RVmain % 2 && -2*remainder == US_EU_ExchangeRate_denominator);
}
```

---

Create a helper function to handle conversions uniformly.

```
RVmain = money_convert(Banka.main, US_EU_ExchangeRate_numerator, US_EU_ExchangeRate_denominator);
```